# Get unformatted order totals amounts in WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, pdf, woocommerce

I have made a copy of the Simple invoice(this is the default), and created a new one, the problem I have is that I can't cast the string value to float. Here is the code:

```
<?php foreach( $this->get_woocommerce_totals() as $key => $total ) : ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <td class="no-borders"></td>
        <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
        <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`the $total['value'];` displays the price in a string format.

I tried using `(float)$total['label']` and `floatval($total['label'])` to cast it but did not work, It gives back a value of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really get that, but you can use the `$key` to target the the `total line type` and you can use `$this->order` that is the instance of the `WC_Order` object with any `WC_Order` method.

To get the gran total unformatted amount (including taxes) you will use `$this->order->get_total()`…

> Some of the available `$keys` are:
>
> - `cart_subtotal`
> - `discount` *(if there is coupons applied)*
> - `shipping`
> - `fee_1234` *(if there is a fee and where `1234` is the item ID… they can be many different)*
> - `tax` (depending on how taxes are displayed on your settings)
> - `payment_method` (it seems hidden by some CSS)
> - `order_total`

So in this code:

```
<?php
    // The line totals data array (in a variable)
    $wc_totals = $this->get_woocommerce_totals();

    // Some order unformatted amounts
    $order_total     = $this->order->get_total(); 
    $order_total_tax = $this->order->get_total_tax();

    ## Manipulating amounts (example) ##

    // Order Total (rounding total amount)
    $wc_totals['order_total']['value'] = strip_tags( wc_price( round( $order_total ) ) );
?>
<?php foreach( $wc_totals as $key => $total ) : ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <td class="no-borders"></td>
        <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
        <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Tested and works.

> You can also add additional totals lines or remove them with unset() and the correct key…

To add a line after the shipping total line (example):

```
 <?php
    // The line totals data array (in a variable)
    $wc_totals = $this->get_woocommerce_totals();

    $wc_new_totals = []; // Initialising

    foreach ( $wc_totals as $key => $total ) {
        $wc_new_totals[$key] = $total;

        if ( $key === 'shipping' ) {
            $wc_new_totals['shipping_avg'] = [
                'label' => __( "Shipping average" ),
                'value' => __( "15 days" ),
            ];
        }
    }
?>
<?php foreach( $wc_new_totals as $key => $total ) : ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <td class="no-borders"></td>
        <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
        <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```