# Can I show taxes only in PDF invoice?

Tags: pdf, woocommerce, invoice

In my woocommerce store, I have set "Display prices in the shop"  & "Display prices during cart and checkout" options to "Including tax" AND added some CSS to hide taxes completely from front-end.

Now the issue is whenever I generate PDF with Woocommerce PDF invoices & packaging slips, it takes the settings from woocommerce and skips the tax calculations in order total.

Is there any way I can reformat order total only for PDF invoice?

Tried code provide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546399/get-unformatted-order-totals-amounts-in-woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips) too but unable to achieve desired output.

Comment: Please share the code you've added to hide taxes.

Comment: It's simple CSS code.  ```.includes_tax { display:none; }```